# Flattening with nullable sibling objects & cousin objects, not collections

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, automapper, flatten

I have a object model like this

```
public class Parent{
 public int Id;
 public string Name;
 public Child Sibling 
}

public class Sibling {
 public int Id;
 public string Name;
 public Cousin Cousin
}

public class Cousin{
 public int Id;
 public string Name;
 public DateTime CreatedDate;
}
```

I'm trying to flatten or project? it to a model like this

```
public class ViewModelSibling {
   public int Id;
   public string Name;
}
public class ViewModel{
 public int ParentId;
 public string ParentName;
 public ViewModelSibling Sibling;
 public ViewModelSibling Cousin;
 public DateTime? CousinCreatedDate;
}
```

where Sibling and Cousin are Nullable

ControllerCode

```
 [HttpPost]
 public virtual ActionResult GetGridItems()
 {
     IQueryable<Parent> parents = GetParentsWhereCriteriaMet();
     var data = parents.Select( p => new ViewModel{
                       ParentId = p.Id,
                       ParentName = p.Name,
                       Sibling = new ViewModelSibling  { Id = p.Sibling.Id, Name = p.Sibling.Name},// if p.Sibling is null and exception is thrown
                       Cousin= new ViewModelSibling  {Id =p.Sibling.Cousin.Id, Name = p.Sibling.Cousin.Name}// if p.Sibling or p.Sibling.Cousin are null and exception is thrown
                       CousinCreatedDate = p.Sibling.Cousin.CreatedDate
                       } )
     return new JsonResult { Data = data };
 }
```

I'm trying to avoid using ToList() because I don't want all of the Parent records to be returned. The ViewModel is going to be bound to a Telerik Grid using Ajax, this handles the paging.
I don't want to use AutoMapper because I don't want all fields and records to be returned.

How do I flatten this model without using ToList()?

Comment: I updated the post with a the question. But in short. if p.Sibling or p.Sibling.Cousin are null and exception is thrown. How do I avoid this without using ToList or cycle through the entire resultset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either

```
Sibling = p.Sibling == null ? null : new ViewModelSibling(...)
```

or

```
Sibling = new ViewModelSibling{ Id = p.Sibling == null ? 0 : p.Sibling.Id, etc ... }
```

depending on your requirements.

etc...

Comment: I can't use ? or ?? without using ToList()

Comment: If you only want a single parent then could you not use 'parent = parents.SingleOrDefault()' ?

Comment: I'm trying to get a collection of parents, Sibling (if it exists), and the sibling's cousin (if it exists)

Comment: Ok, so have you investigated Include("<table name>")?  e.g. parents.Include("Sibling").Include("Cousin").Select(...) and then use ?: or ??